# Maximum vs supremum of a discontinuous function over a closed bounded set

Tags: analysis, continuity, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

The statement "Any continuous function must have a maximum on a closed bounded set" is made in [these notes](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Edav/spectral.pdf).

We are looking at a function $f: S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. I can see why closedness and boundedness are necessary but am trying to see why continuity is required to conclude that

$$\sup\limits_{S} f = \max\limits_{S} f$$

What is an example of a discontinuous function over a closed and bounded set for which the result above does not hold?

Secondly, is there an example of a discontinuous but bounded function (i.e. the range of $f$ is bounded) over a closed and bounded set for which the above result does not hold?

Comment: The issue is not that $\sup$ and $\max$ may be different from each other. The issue is that $\max$ may not exist, while $\sup$ does. For an example take $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ with $f(1)=0$ and $f(x)=x$ otherwise.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos ah I see - you comment answers my question. Happy to accept it as an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The supremum of the set $(a,b)$ is $b$ but the maximum does not exist you can use this to answer your question.